# Change default Maven path?

Tags: java, maven

Is it possible to change the default path where Maven places a *.war or a *.jar after the install process? Can I alter this to a personalized path? If yes, how would I do that? All my projects currently follow the following paths:

```
--- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ myProject ---
Installing /home/myuser/NetBeansProjects/myProject/target/myProject-1.0.war to /home/myuser/.m2/repository/com/allproj/myProject/1.0/myProject-1.0.war
```

Comment: What are trying to achieve by doing that?

Comment: My intention is only put the *.war directly into my Wildfly-directory or my *.jar files directly onto my desktop. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can customize it.

Just uncomment below lines in **settings.xml** file inside conf folder of maven installation directory.

```
<!-- localRepository
   | The path to the local repository maven will use to store artifacts.
   |
   | Default: ${user.home}/.m2/repository
  <localRepository>/path/to/local/repo</localRepository>
  -->
```

You can uncomment it and add path in localRepository tag for your new location,then maven will start downloading all the artifact and install your app in the new location.

Comment: Hi @MadProgrammer and thanks for answering so quickly! But what I wanted to do was not move the entire Maven directory to another place. My intention is only put the *.war directly into my Wildfly-directory or my *.jar files directly onto my desktop. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

In general it's not a good idea to mess with the maven-install-plugin for the purpose of delivering artifacts to a specific destination. The purpose of the install plugin is to store not only the artifact but a bunch of associated metadata into a local `artifact repository`.

You can use the [WildFly Maven Plugin](https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/examples/deployment-example.html) if you want to install your WAR file into a WildFly instance.

Alternatively you can use the [copy goal](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html) of the [Maven Dependency Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) to place a copy of your WAR file (or any other artifact) wherever you need.